# Targeting a nested iframe using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, excel, office365, puppeteer

At the moment I'm trying to create some E2E tests which require logging into Excel online and then uploading an extension.

I was able to login, open Excel and click the upload plugin button, however, I cannot get any further.

So far I've figured out there are 2 iframes, one nested in another.

I access the first one once I open Excel

```js
let targetIFrame = await this.page.frames().find(f => f.name() === 'sdx_ow_iframe');
```

The tricky part about the second one is that it only appears in the DOM after I click the "Upload Plugin" button and it is nested in the one I accessed above.

I've tried different delays etc, but it just looks like puppeteer does not see it.

Comment: It'd be good to see the actual site or a [mcve] of it along with your runnable code so far. (I know this is an old question so unlikely to be clarified, but I'd like to use it as a canonical for nested iframes)

Answer (score 0):

Base on my research, you can construct an implementation to find the iframe include in the parent frame.

Please test the code as below:

```
/**
* @return {!Promise<ElementHandle>}
*/
async ownerFrame() {
  if (!this._frame._parentFrame)
    throw new Error('No parent frame');

  const rootElementHandle = await this._frame.$('*');
  const rootElementDescriptionHandle = await this._client.send('DOM.describeNode', { objectId: rootElementHandle._remoteObject.objectId });

  const parentsIframes = await this._frame._parentFrame.$$('iframe');
  if (!parentsIframes.length)
    throw new Error('No iframe elements found in parent');

  return parentsIframes.find(async parentsIframe => {
    const iframeDescription = await this._client.send('DOM.describeNode', { objectId: parentsIframe._remoteObject.objectId, pierce: true, depth: 2 });
    const iframesRootDescription = iframeDescription.node.contentDocument.children[0];
    return iframesRootDescription.backendNodeId === rootElementDescriptionHandle.node.backendNodeId;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was able to get to that iframe using frame.$() and then elementHandle.contentFrame()