# Puppeteer-WaitForSelector() with nested I frames

Tags: iframe, puppeteer

Puppeteer-WaitForSelector() , I have to use this function with a selector present in nested iframe. Is it possible? If not, please suggest some other alternative where I can delay my functionality based on the selector present in iframe.
I do not want to use waitFor() as I don't want to give hard coded time.
NOTE: Iframes are nested

Comment: Sure, it's possible, but you should share your target URL and code so far to get more precise assistance. Possible dupes: [Targeting a nested iframe using puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52074528/targeting-a-nested-iframe-using-puppeteer) and [Puppeteer handling nested iframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68561073/puppeteer-handling-nested-iframes)

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over [`page.frames()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageframes) till the right iframe is found and then use [`frame.waitForSelector()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#framewaitforselectorselector-options).