# Puppeteer handling nested iframes

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, e2e-testing

I have an iframe for captcha verification within a parent iframe.

```
<iframe login>
"login code"
    <iframe captcha>
    "captcha code"
    </iframe>
<iframe>
```

I'm attempting to 'click' and interact with this nested iframe for captcha verification with no luck.

```
const frameHandle = await page.$("iframe");
const frame = await frameHandle.contentFrame();

const childframeHandle = await page.$("reCAPTCHA")
const childframe = (await childframeHandle.contentFrame()).click();
```

What would be the best approach for interacting with the captcha. I've successfully interacted with the parent frame for entering the login username and password. However the click iframe seems to be a little more complex and i'm unsure how to approach.

Comment: Maybe `await frame.$("reCAPTCHA")` instead of `await page.$("reCAPTCHA")`?

Comment: Also, it seems you need a selector for some frame element in [`frame.click()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#frameclickselector-options), i.e. in the last line.